# Как отправить Telegram JSON объект?

Tags: telegram-bot, telegram

Имеется объект JSON

```
{"chat_id":123456789,"text":"test","reply_markup":[{"text":"button","callback_data":"click"}]}
```

Каким образом данный JSON отправить телеграм боту?

P.S. Не интересуют библиотеки. У меня конкретный вопрос.

Comment: Ну, на JAVA например вот так https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40100358/telegram-bot-json-post-request-doesnt-work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решено

```
$keyboard = [
    'inline_keyboard' => [
        [
            ['text' => 'button', 'callback_data' => 'click']
        ]
    ]
];

$message = [
    'chat_id' => '123456789',
    'text' => 'test',
    'reply_markup' => json_encode($keyboard)
];

$url = 'https://api.telegram.org/bot123456789/sendMessage';

$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $message);
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```